# Whats the correct way to send multiple (text-)files to REST Service

Tags: file, rest, jax-rs

I use JAX-RS 2.0 and ask myself what`s the best way to send multiple text files.

My client application creates multiple textfiles that have to be processed in my REST Service method in one run.

At the moment, I send a request for every single textfile and wait until all are sent.

I would prefer to send the files in one request in form of an array. Is it possible to do that? And could anybody give me a example, how this could look? I tried myself but I don`t know which MediaType to use. A single file can be send with MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN. If I use MULTIPART_FORM_DATA the REST Service always throws the following Exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class [Ljava.io.File;, genericType=class [Ljava.io.File;.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:495)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:270)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:182)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:227)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:412)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:321)
at test.controller.TestRestReportController.testSendReportToServer(TestRestReportController.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Can anybody tell me how to handle this. I have already searched the web for useful information but didn`t find a matching solution.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need the jersey-multipart extension. A useful how-to is at http://aruld.info/handling-multiparts-in-restful-applications-using-jersey/

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment, but I still don`t know how to send a Array of Files to server. Can you please provide me a short example?
What MediaType to use? I tried with MultiPart, but don`t know what to insert into bodyPart... File? InputStream? And what MediaType? I cant`figure it out.

Comment: Well, you haven't actually posted an example of the code you used to produce the stack trace. There is most likely nothing wrong with your existing code, you just need to register the MessageBodyProvider from jersey-multipart